# HTTP GET request to stackoverflow.com returns status code 301

Tags: c#, http, dns, http-status-code-301

What am I essencially doing is: I input URL (stackoverflow.com) in browser, catch HTTP request with proxy, proceed it to website, then get response from website and relay it back to browser.
In theory it should work just fine, but in practice I get response with "Moved Permanently" and "Location: https://stackoverflow.com/". If I understand it correctly, I need to get this location address and replace old address in HTTP request ("GET http://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1" -> "GET https://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1") and then make request again.
However, that's where I stuck. When I make new request, website responses with same status code - 301, no matter what I do.

That's what I am doing at proxy side:
Get list of IP addresses by using Dns.GetHostAddresses() - it returns 4 addresses:

```
151.101.65.69
151.101.129.69
151.101.193.69
151.101.1.69
```

Then I connect to each address and send this request (which I got from browser):

```
"GET http://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nCookie: prov=0014938e-7640-15fd-486c-9e6cb05cd5b1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n\r\n"
```

I then get response:

```
"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nLocation: https://stackoverflow.com/\r\nX-Request-Guid: 080d3919-7d02-4e48-9348-b9dc8b5b08f6\r\nContent-Length: 143\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nDate: Mon, 26 Feb 2018 17:56:59 GMT\r\nVia: 1.1 varnish\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nX-Served-By: cache-ams4441-AMS\r\nX-Cache: MISS\r\nX-Cache-Hits: 0\r\nX-Timer: S1519667819.162626,VS0,VE76\r\nVary: Fastly-SSL\r\nX-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off\r\n\r\n<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>\r\n<h2>Object moved to <a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/\">here</a>.</h2>\r\n</body></html>\r\n"
```

But then even if I change "GET http://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1" to "GET https://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1", nothing changes, every of this four IPs return same response.

Am I mising something important? Maybe I should include another tag or change something else in new request header?

Comment: What is confusing here exactly? Stack Overflow will redirect everything to the secure protocol.

Comment: It means that I don't need to change anything in request, I just need to use SSLStream or something similar for secure connection? I am not yet implemented secure stream in proxy code because I thought I need to figure out redirection first.

Comment: I don't want to sound patronising, but if you are struggling to understand what is going on here, then you're going to have major trouble implementing a proxy. There's a lot more to it than just being a pass through.

Comment: Yes, I understand that and I am trying to figure it out bit by bit. For now I just need simple pass-through (clear) proxy that just relays requests from browser to website and back. I already succeeded in building simple HTTP pass-through proxy so my next step is to get HTTPS working, but I encountered "301" problem. For now I just need to know if I got redirection process from code 301 right.

Comment: You should pass the redirection back to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked, now I am getting "Secure Connection Failed" and that is what I wanted to see in a first place when I was testing proxy.
For some reason I thought that browser can't figure out how to redirect by itself and I need to do it manually.